# adobe edge animate on my Joomla based website

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, adobe

My designer has created a 1160x774 container for some interactive animation with adobe edge animate on my Joomla based website. I can't get this (folder with `js/html/css`) to load.

What do I need to change/add to make this possible?

Comment: You need to explain what you have tried etc. This is not enough information to provide help.

Comment: Fix the problem, you need to put the URL in a iframe like below 

<div id="Web-App">
<iframe src="your-websitepage" width="1160" height="745">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
</div>